# Blue Green Deployment in Azure spring apps

Tags: azure, azure-spring-cloud, azure-spring-boot

Started exploring blue/green deployment in azure springs. I was able to create staging app and promote it to production. When I want to test the staging app I am getting a URL with basic authentication. Without setting the Basic authentication header the request is getting rejected at ngnix. My application has a different method of authentication so I cannot provide the authentication header ngnix is requesting for. Is there a way to test the staging endpoint (Run automated tests) before marking it as production.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure Spring Apps service only allow clients access the test endpoint with the given authentication.
But in the future the platform may be able to support more flexible settings. For example, allow customer to set their own access token.

A possible workaround for now:
Create two different Apps in the same service instance. For example: myapp-prod, myapp-staging.